# Eclipse won't detect my phone

Tags: android

So I have been developing apps for android and I'm using my phone to run it.

I have been doing this for a while but when i plugged my phone into my laptop again it said that it started to install the driver again but now fails.

Now I can't use my phone to debug my apps.

Does anyone know how to fix this?
This occurred more than once.

Comment: you should download and install [Android ADB Driver](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html) on your machine

Comment: @ABFORCE But it worked before, it happend when i plugged the device again

Comment: @user2982786 Reboot your Windows or phone or Eclipse may solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It usually happen when Eclipse does not found Andriod Debug Bridge(adb) somehow.

So, in order to sort out this problem you can download "**Universal adb**".

Its a software which installs adb required for compatibility between your device and 
Eclipse IDE.

First you just need to connect your device with your laptop and run the Universal adb software.
Hit the install button. And its all done.

I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

When this happens to me I just restart the adb server. Open a terminal and go to the directory where adb is located

```
cd ...something.../android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools  (or something similar)
```

And then restart the server with this command series

```
./adb kill-server; ./adb start-server; ./adb devices
```